# Rcpp sourceCpp with parallel foreach

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a function **foo** written in Rcpp which I can utilize in my R session through sourceCpp.

I also have a cluster of machines using R's parallel makePSOCKCluster.  I want to run a parallel foreach loop across these machines which will utilize foo.  I can see the function being exported through foreach, but I think only the pointer to the Rcpp function is exported.  How can I make sure that the function foo itself is also exported?