# Why doesn't my foreach loop execute an Rcpp function in parallel?

Tags: foreach, rcpp

I seem to have the same problem as this poster from 8 years ago: [Rcpp sourceCpp with parallel foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418655/rcpp-sourcecpp-with-parallel-foreach).

Let me describe this in the abstract first: I have defined an Rcpp function with `cppFunction`, let's call it `med_Cpp`. It takes two arguments as input:

- int `wordfreq`
- NumericVector `priorinteger`

and returns as output a NumericVector. (I share it at the bottom but it's a very basic function with absolutely nothing fancy with environments or stuff like that. What `med_Cpp` does is, it returns a vector that distributes `wordfreq` elements over `length(priorinteger)` bins such that the resulting (posterior) distribution has the smallest possible Kullback-Leibler divergence from the prior. For instance, `med_Cpp(17, c(1,3,5,9,16))` returns `c(1, 2, 2, 4, 8)` because there's no way to distribute 17 items over 5 'bins' with the prior `c(1,3,5,9,16)` and get a smaller KLD.)

That function `med_Cpp`

1. works properly when called interactively on its own, i.e., `med_Cpp(17, c(1,3,5,9,16))`;
2. works properly when called in a foreach loop with `%do%`, i.e., **no** parallel execution like this:

```
registerDoParallel(cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores()-21, outfile=""))
lows <- foreach(i=seq(unique.freqs), .combine=c) %do% {
   med_Cpp(unique.freqs[i], c(1,3,5,9,16)))
}; stopCluster(cl); gc()
```

3. does **not** work when called in a `foreach` loop with `%dopar%`, i.e., **with** parallel execution like this: (same code as above, only change is `dopar`)

```
registerDoParallel(cl <- makePSOCKcluster(detectCores()-21, outfile=""))
lows <- foreach(i=seq(unique.freqs), .combine=c) %dopar% {
   med_Cpp(unique.freqs[i], c(1,3,5,9,16)))
}; stopCluster(cl); gc()
```

I've read up on things a bit and also tried ChatGPT and Google Bard. But the responses/examples I got suggest that my script *should* be working. For instance, Google Bard gave this example of a script that works (condensed):

```
library(Rcpp); library(doParallel)
# Define your Rcpp function
cppFunction('double my_rcpp_function(double x, double y) {
   return x * y;
}')
x <- 1:10 # Create a vector of values to iterate over
results <- foreach(i = x, .combine=c) %dopar% {
  my_rcpp_function(i, i+2)
}
results
```

Why does *this* work and mine doesn't? Other Rcpp functions of mine inserted in there also don't work, but Google Bard's onoe above doesn't and for the life of me I cannot see any difference between them. Any tips would be much appreciated!

---

Appendix: med_Cpp

```
cppFunction('NumericVector med_Cpp(int wordfreq, NumericVector priorinteger) {
   int n = priorinteger.size();
   double sumpriorinteger = sum(priorinteger);

   NumericVector priorprop = clone(priorinteger);
   for(int qwe = 0; qwe < n; ++qwe) { priorprop[qwe] = priorinteger[qwe]/sumpriorinteger; };

   NumericVector mosteven(n);
   for(int qwe = 0; qwe < n; ++qwe) {
      mosteven[qwe] = floor(priorprop[qwe] * wordfreq)-1;
      if (mosteven[qwe] < 0) { mosteven[qwe] = 0; }
   };

   while (sum(mosteven)!=wordfreq) {
      NumericVector KLDcollector(n); for(int qwe = 0; qwe < n; ++qwe) { KLDcollector[qwe] = 0; };

      if (sum(mosteven) < wordfreq) {

         for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            NumericVector currentmosteven = clone(mosteven);
            currentmosteven[j] = currentmosteven[j]+1;

            double sumpost = 0; double sumprior = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
               sumpost += currentmosteven[k];
               sumprior += priorinteger[k];
            }
            double KLD = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
               if (currentmosteven[k]>0) {
                  double postprop = currentmosteven[k]/sumpost;
                  double priorprop = priorinteger[k]/sumprior;
                  KLD += postprop * log2(postprop/priorprop);
               }
            }
            KLDcollector[j] = KLD;
         }
         double minKLD = min(KLDcollector);
         int output = -1;
         for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            if (KLDcollector[k]==minKLD) {
               output = k;
               break;
            }
         }
         mosteven[output] = mosteven[output]+1;
      }
   }
   return(mosteven);
}')
```

Comment: Please search for prior discussions explaining why `sourceCpp()` and `cppFunction()` do *not* work as the (compiled) function remains local to your current session. To work in parallel, you work and _need to load the worker functions from local packages accessible to the workers_.